# Geocoder constructor cannot be defined

Tags: java, android, google-geocoder

Hopefully this is a simple one guys. Im trying to create a geocoder object instance. I am getting an error that the constructor for the class is undefined. I don't understand why as I am supplying a context and default.ENGLISH.

I have the import and I have tried the context as both simply 'this' and 'context.this'.

```
import com.google.android.maps.GeoPoint;
```

This is the code in my method:

```
    public String convertGpToLoc(double lat, double longg)
    {

        Geocoder gc = new Geocoder(CityClickListener.this, Locale.US);

        List<Address> addresses = gc.getFromLocation(lat, longg, 1);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        if (addresses.size() > 0) {
        Address address = addresses.get(0);
        for (int i = 0; i < address.getMaxAddressLineIndex(); i++)
        sb.append(address.getAddressLine(i)).append("\n");
        sb.append(address.getLocality()).append("\n");
        sb.append(address.getPostalCode()).append("\n");
        sb.append(address.getCountryName());

        return sb.toString();

        }

        return null;

    }
}
```

Comment: @iTech Same issue sadly.

Comment: Is `PostalCodeAdapter` extends `Context` (e.g. Activity)?

Comment: @iTech. It is actually in my cityCliclListener class, i changed it to this and still have the same issue. No it dosent extend an activity base class. I have added the whole class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The type of the first argument should be `Context`

So based on your code, try he following:

```
Geocoder gc = new Geocoder(ctx, Locale.US);
```

Comment: I extended the class to an activity and it worked fine. Many thanks for you great answer.